# Implementing Iter for doubly-linked list

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

Problem: Being new to python I am currently trying to learn the ropes, getting a better handle on the difference between an array and a linked structure. I've attempted creating a linked list class to assist in getting a better understanding of the language and its structures. 
What I have written so far:

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, val, prior=None, next=None):
            self.val = val
            self.prior = prior
            self.next  = next

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = LinkedList.Node(None) 
        self.head.prior = self.head.next = self.head 
        self.length = 0

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self)==0:
            return '[]'
        else:
            return '[' +  ', '.join(str(x) for x in self) + ']'

    def __repr__(self):
        """Supports REPL inspection. (Same behavior as `str`.)"""
        return str(self)

    def __len__(self):
        """Implements `len(self)`"""
        return self.length

    def __iter__(self):
        """Supports iteration (via `iter(self)`)"""
        cursor = self.head
        while cursor:
            yield cursor.val
            cursor = cursor.next

    def append(self, value):
        n = LinkedList.Node(value, prior=self.head.prior, next=self.head)
        n.prior.next = n.next.prior = n
        self.length += 1
```

Testing the code below, I'll have a problem where the kernel task won't end, or the debugger will point to line 7 of the test code where it failed. I don't think my `__repr__` method is wrong which is why I ask, how could I edit the `__iter__` method body to fix this issue? I thought all I had to do was loop through the values in cursor.

```
from unittest import TestCase
tc = TestCase()

lst = LinkedList()
for d in (10, 20, 30, 40, 50):
    lst.append(d)
tc.assertEqual('[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]', str(lst))
tc.assertEqual('[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]', repr(lst))
```

Comment: You don't show your `append` method ... consider the possibility that its accidentally creating circles in your structure ...

Comment: When posting code, please make sure what you post is runnable and reproduces the problem you describe when you run it. The code you've posted has no definition of `append`.

Comment: 1. I don't see an implementation of `append` here, which is rather important. 2. Implementing `__repr__` in terms of `__str__` is strange; typically, you implement `__repr__` first, and leave `__str__` unimplemented if you don't need separate behavior (`__repr__` will be used in place of `__str__` if `__str__` is not defined). 3. Your `__init__` indicates you're using `self.head` as the indicator for end of iteration, not `None` or the like; if `append` follows the same rules, that would explain the problem; you're iterating circularly.

Comment: Is your list intended to be circularly linked? Is the initial `self.head` supposed to be a sentinel node?

Comment: My mistake it got cut off, edited. and yes `self.head` is the sentinel node

Answer (score 3):

Since you say `self.head` is the sentinel node, your `__iter__` is incorrect; it's testing as if it expects to find a "falsy" value (e.g. `None`), when being circularly linked, it will never reach such a point. Presumably, you want something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Supports iteration (via `iter(self)`)"""
    cursor = self.head.next  # Must advance past non-valued head
    # Done when we get back to head
    while cursor is not self.head:
        yield cursor.val
        cursor = cursor.next
```

Comment: You're still yielding the sentinel's `None` value of `val`. You should probably start at `cursor = self.head.next` and test `while cursor is not self.head`.

Comment: @user2357112: Was already fixing that once I saw the `append` method which made it clear `head` shouldn't be part of the iteration. :-)

Comment: I tried this implementation but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular list.  I diagnosed this with the usual high-tech method: the print statement.  :-)

I inserted a couple of prints into your **str** method:

```
def __str__(self):
    if len(self)==0:
        return '[]'
    else:
        print "NODE VALUE:", self.head.val
        for x in self:
            print "LIST ITEM", x
        return '[' +  ', '.join(str(x) for x in self) + ']'
```

... and cut back the test a touch:

```
lst = LinkedList()
for d in (10, 20, 30, 40, 50):
    lst.append(d)
print "str\t", str(lst)
```

Your method loops through the five expected values and a **None** header.

```
LIST ITEM None
LIST ITEM 10
LIST ITEM 20
LIST ITEM 30
LIST ITEM 40
LIST ITEM 50
LIST ITEM None
LIST ITEM 10
LIST ITEM 20
LIST ITEM 30
LIST ITEM 40
LIST ITEM 50
LIST ITEM None
LIST ITEM 10
LIST ITEM 20
```